# RX100 front shifter does not click and falls back to inner chainring

Tags: shifter

On my road bike with Shimano RX100 combined brake/shifters I noticed that the shifter for the front chainring no longer clicks and so fails to keep the chain on the shifted-to outer chainring. Instead, it moves back to the inner chain ring. I haven't looked closely yet, but do the symptoms sound familiar to anyone? I am somewhat reluctant to disassemble the shifter.

Comment: How cold is it where you are?  It's fairly common for the grease in such shifters to stiffen with age and low temps, such that the pawl that holds the shift position doesn't move when it should.  If simply warming up doesn't fix it then usually a shot of spray lube does.  (But discussing *which* spray lube to use could start a religious war here.)

Comment: It's around 5ºC here, the shifter is over 10 years old, and barely used. So a lack of lubrication sounds plausible.

Comment: I believe this discussion around [Why does my front derailleur not work when it is cold?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/27326/why-does-my-front-derailleur-not-work-when-it-is-cold) provides enough information. I'll close my question.

Comment: I've serviced an RSX100 brifter and multiple pod shifters.  Its pretty straightforward, and some notes are at https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/35662/19705

Comment: I can report that a generous application of WD40 has improved the situation already.